# How do I change the color of the icons and text that appear on the toolbar?

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design, theming, mdc

This might look like a problem that has been asked before but actually it is different. All the other questions are either about the support libraries themes or some other older theme. In my app I am using an MDC theme and it seems to work very differently.

**Goal**: I want to change the color of my toolbar to the same color as the background of my whole activity (which I believe is defined by `android:windowBackground`) to achieve a design that looks something like the [material theme builder app](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android-examples/tree/develop/MaterialThemeBuilder) or some google apps like Google News or Google Photos. Since in light mode that would mean changing the toolbar to white, that would also mean changing the icons, buttons and the text (like the app's name or current destinations name, the overflow menu icon: the three dots, the up button) that appears on the toolbar to black or something darker. I **also** want the status bar to be of the same color as the background.

*Note: I have tried several common practices in several different ways but none of them really worked. I can't really list every one of them since that would be very tedious*

themes.xml used for light mode:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="hi_dictionary_theme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/orange_light</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/orange_light</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/on_primary_dark</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/green_dark</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/green_dark</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/on_primary_light</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary</item>
        <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar" tools:targetApi="23">true</item>
        <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/overflow_icon</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

colors.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="orange_dark">#6F4C45</color>
    <color name="orange_light">#9B6D5A</color>
    <color name="green_dark">#166F22</color>
    <color name="green_light">#70C35C</color>
    <color name="on_primary_dark">#000</color>
    <color name="on_primary_light">#FFF</color>
    <color name="dark_background">#151515</color>
    <color name="light_background">#ffffff</color>
</resources>
```

styles.xml

```
    <style name="overflow_icon" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow">
        <item name="android:tint">?attr/colorOnPrimary</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```